# BCS connecting to Oracle Database with BDC Model

Tags: 2010, bcs, external-content-type, oracle

Firstly I'm open to suggestions if people have better solutions or ideas. 
I want to create a Dashboard with CRUD operations from the Oracle data and planning on using SPD External Content Types.

I've installed BCS on the server and need to make a connection to Oracle. In SPD > External Content Type  I get options for .NET, SQL Server, WCF Service and no Oracle at the moment.

I've seen some 3rd part tools to do this but want to know if I can create my own XML file and add it to the BCS section in Central Admin.
This link on the Microsoft site shows a sample of the xml file but not sure if it will work the way I intend. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff464424(v=office.14).aspx

Do I need to ONLY copy the code on the linked page into notepad and make a few adjustments and add into BCS (Import BDC Model) ?

Do I need to use Visual Studio as mentioned in several articles?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Take note of this crucial point.**

> If the retrieving items from the Oracle database are more than 2000 items
> You will face performance issues so I advise you to check [**External**
> **List Limitation**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/external-list-limitations-in-sharepoint/) before you try to use BCS even if you increase its default max to absolute max via PowerShell.

**When it comes to integrating Oracle with Visual Studio, you should consider...**

- Make sure that the Instance Oracle Client and Oracle Data Provider for .Net (x64) have been installed.
- Open Visual Studio > Tools Menu > Select Connect to Database.
- Select Oracle DB and for data provider select .Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle > Click Continue.
- Add Connectiontion based on tnsnames.ora file

> For a real scenario, you can also check [**Connect to Oracle DB via Visual Studio**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/connect-to-oracle-db-from-visual-studio/)

Comment: Hi
Im not sure if the items retrieved from Oracle will ever be greater than 2000. If I was not to use ECT's then what other options are available ? Is another choice to create a VS solution and add to SharePoint (i.e. webpart /application page)?

Comment: In my opinion, The appropriate solution is creating a web service that reads from the oracle database then consume it in your SharePoint solutions. check also **[Connect to Oracle DB via Visual Studio](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/connect-to-oracle-db-on-visual-studio-2010/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharePoint Designer to do this. In Visual Studio you will have more possibilities but it is way more complicated. I think for your purpose SharePoint Designer will do the job.

[Ingo Karstein: Create a simple BCS connection with SharePoint Designer 2010](https://blog.kenaro.com/2011/02/23/walkthrough-create-a-simple-bcs-connection-with-sharepoint-designer-2010/)

this helped me a lot to get started with BDC connections ;)

Comment: Need to connect to Oracle so solution provided is not applicable.